# Ansible regex escape character

Tags: regex, string, ansible, character

I am trying to manipulate a string in Ansible with regex_replace.
Unfortunately I am not able to get the requested result.

Input string:  home0home
Output string: home1home

Code:

```yaml
  - name: String manipulator
    set_fact:
     string: "{{ string| regex_replace('^(.{4}).(.*)$','\\1 1\\2') }}"
  - name:
    debug: msg="{{ string }}"
```

Output:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "home 1home"
}
```

How to get rid of the empty space?
If I remove the space in regex, it fails.

Comment: Use `'\\g<1>1\\2'`

Comment: Thank you! that works, is there any other solution, without the group naming? I am curious about the escape characters but non of them are working for me.

Comment: `regex_replace('(?<=^.{4}).','1')`